# Save() not updating my record in Database Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an application using grails 2.5.1 I am trying to update multiple domain objects of the same type from a list. When I try saving there is no error and even if I use failOnError and flush it will still not fail neither does it save. When I use a debugger, I can see that my object has the updated values at the time of saving and after but when I reload the objects in other forms the will not be updated. I have also tried waiting for the session to close but its not changing. Here is a a piece of the code that is saving.

```
def saveMultipleMissingAssets(MultipleAssetCommand command) {
        command.assets.each { a ->
            Asset asset = Asset.findById((long)a.id)
            asset.properties['missing'] = a.properties
            asset = asset.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
            if(asset.hasErrors()){
                print asset.properties
            }
        }
    }
```

Where I am using findById(a.id) I have tried using get and read but the result is the same.

This is part of my view

```
<g:each var="asset" in="${assetInstanceList}" status="i">
                            <div id="asset${i}">
                                <g:hiddenField name='assets[${i}].id' value='$asset.id'/>
                            </div>
                            <tr>
                                <td>${asset.id}</td>
                                <th>${asset.assetType}</th>
                                <td>${asset.serialNumber}</td>
                                <td><g:checkBox name='assets[${i}].missing' value='1' checked="${asset.missing}"
                                                class="checkbox1"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </g:each>
```

and My objects look Command objects are:

```
class SingleAssetCommand {
    int id
    Boolean missing
}
```

and

```
@Validateable
class MultipleAssetCommand {
    List<SingleAssetCommand> assets = [].withDefault {new SingleAssetCommand()}
}
```

And the domain I am trying to update look like this

```
class Asset {
    AssetType assetType
    Integer assetId
    String serialNumber
    Boolean missing
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    Employee employee

    static hasMany = [allocations: Allocation, trackingEvents:TrackingEvent]

    static constraints = {
        assetId(nullable: true)
        assetType()
        serialNumber(nullable: true)
        missing(nullable: true)
        employee nullable: true //,lazy: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        missing index: 'asset_missing_idx'
        employee index: 'asset_allocated_idx'
    }

    String toString() {
        assetType.toString() + ": " + serialNumber
    }
}
```

part of the controller which prepares the view is as follows:

```
def multiEdit = {
    List<Asset> list = Asset.list()
    [assetInstanceList: list]
 }
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code where `assetInstanceList` is populated? I assume this is a `command object` and not the actual `domain`. Correct?

Comment: Hi Armaiti, It is the actual object and not the command. I have added the part you requested please have a look.

Comment: Have you looked at Asset table? Do you see your updates? It looks like Asset domain populates property value from command object.

Comment: There are no updates in the asset table